# FlashList's rendered size is not usable

Tags: react-native, shopify, react-native-flatlist

I am migrating from `FlatList` to `FlashList`, i have upgraded my expo sdk from `45.0.0` to `46.0.0` and on implementing the `FlashList` as in the shopify/flashlist documentation i get the following warning

> FlashList's rendered size is not usable. Either the height or width is too small (<2px). Please make sure that the parent view of the list has a valid size. FlashList will match the size of the parent.

It was working fine with `FlatList`, only that it took to much time to load data from api,,,thats why i decided to switch to `FlashList`. Anyone know how to fix this?Any help is appreciated. here is my code

**renderItem function**

```js
    const renderItem = ({ item: product }) => {
    return (
      <Product
        category={product.bp_product_category}
        itemname={product.bp_product_name}
        price={product.bp_product_selling_price}
        mass={product.bp_product_mass}
        unitofmass={product.bp_product_unit_of_mass}
        productID={product._id}
      />
    );
    };


      const keyExtractor = useCallback((item) => item._id, []);
      const filteredproducts = products.filter((product, i) =>
      product.bp_product_name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
       );
```

**FlashList it self**

```js
    <View style={{flex:1, width:'100%', height:'100%'}} >
       <FlashList
          keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
          data={filteredproducts}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          estimatedItemSize={200}
          numColumns={2}
          refreshing={refresh}
          onRefresh={Refresh}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            // alignSelf: "flex-start",
            // justifyContent: "space-between",
            // paddingBottom: 120,
          }}
      />
   </View>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `flex: 1` in your contentContainerStyle? Or giving it an exact height

Comment: this brings another warning FlashList only supports padding related props and backgroundColor in contentContainerStyle

Comment: Try adding it in the style prop then?

Comment: this list doesnt support using style prop , it will bring a warning, the only option is to wrap the list in a parent and apply the styling to it. Which i did but still the error is there

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the same issue and a warning `FlashList rendered size is not useable` and the screen was blank .

According to [FlashList docs](https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/docs/known-issues/) we should use it inside a wrapper like `View` with hardcoded height style number like this :

```
<View style={{ height: 200, width: Dimensions.get("screen").width }}>
    <FlashList
       data={DATA}
       renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
       estimatedItemSize={200}
    />
</View>
```

If I was in your shoes I would make a simple flashlist work perfectly fine then I'd implement the list I want and add more to it .

This fixed my problem . Hope you make it work .

Comment: Is it better the View component's height value can be retrieved like what you did with the width?

Comment: @userIndulgeInDChord Yes that way it will be the same size on all mobile devices with different height and width and fully responsive .

Comment: this answer is not right: the width is always 100% by its nature, and assigning it to Screen width can create display issues since the list could be cotained in parent container with its own dimensions (smaller then the screen width)

Answer (score 8):

From the docs:

> ...So, make sure that the parent of the list mounts with a valid size (>=2px) and FlashList will match the size of its parent. ...

So, I decided to wrap the *FlashList* into a *View* and set *minHeight* property to 2, which satisfies the statement from the docs.

```
<View style={{minHeight: 2}}>
    <FlashList ... /> 
</View>
```

As a result, the warning went away.

Comment: It's hilarious that this works.

Answer (score 3):

If you place FlashList inside a View with justifyContent=center and alignItem=center, you should received this error. Try to remove it like this:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <FlashList data={must not empty} ... />
</View>
```

Comment: worked like magic, thank you

Answer (score 3):

For me worked changing in parent view alignItems: 'center' to alignItems: 'flex-start' and adding flex: 1.

```
<View style={{alignItems: 'flex-start', flex: 1}}>
 <FlashList ... /> 
 </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me I just needed to add Flex: 1 to my View

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: '#fff', flex: 1}}>
      {fabrics && (
        <FlashList
          data={fabrics}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          estimatedItemSize={180}
        />
      )}
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before trying `flex: 1`, try `flexGrow: 1` on your parent container. This fixed the issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

set minHeight: 200 it's okay for me

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, minHeight: 200 }}>
            <FlashList
                keyExtractor={({ title }) => title}
                data={DATA}
                renderItem={() => <Item />}
                onRefresh={() => true}
                estimatedItemSize={200} />
    </View>
    </View>
```